# HitTest is obsolete, what is the new format to get my buttons working again with UI image(once GUITexture)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, touch

I'm having issues trying to resolve this issue I have from migrating my old Unity5 game to Unity 2020. I've got everything running again, except for this issue with my buttons not working because of an update to "HitTest" being obsolete. What can I do to make this work without completely starting from scratch?

```
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary && hitButton.HitTest(touch.position))
        {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MoveRotation(80);

        }
```

Comment: I've tried using UI Button, but I don't know how to make it run a (multiple)rigidbody2d in my scene. It's pretty much a 2D pinball game and my flippers are no longer working, but works with input.getkey. How can I change: if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) to a touch button?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a Canvas as a child of the gameobject with the rigidbody2d/collider2d components, then put the button on that canvas, and then in your code above, keep a reference to the canvas and the button that lives there.

Then, you can use `GraphicRaycaster.Raycast`. Modified version of the source code in the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.GraphicRaycaster.Raycast.html):

```
// Attach this script to your Canvas GameObject.
// Also attach a GraphicsRaycaster component to your canvas by clicking the 
//     Add Component button in the Inspector window.
// Also make sure you have an EventSystem in your scene

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RaycasterTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;

    void Start()
    {
        //Fetch the Raycaster from the GameObject (the Canvas)
        m_Raycaster = GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();      
    }

    public bool TestTouch(Touch touch, GameObject target)
    {
        //Set up the new Pointer Event
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        //Set the Pointer Event Position to that of the touch position
        pointerEventData.position = touch.position;

        //Create a list of Raycast Results
        List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Raycast using the Graphics Raycaster and touch position
        m_Raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);

        foreach (RaycastResult result in results)
        {
            if (result.gameObject == target) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So basically the hierarchy looks something like this at runtime:

```
Flipper object [ Rigidbody2D, Collider2D, questionScript (references RaycasterTester and Button) ]
L Canvas object [ Canvas (world space), GraphicRaycaster, RaycasterTester ]
  L Button object [ Button, Image, hitButtonScript (?) ]

(somewhere in scene) [ EventSystem ]
```

Then, in the Question Script, get a reference to the instance of the above script then call the `TestTouch` method:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary 
            && raycasterTester.TestTouch(touch, hitButton.gameObject))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MoveRotation(80);
          
        // break to avoid being turned by multiple touches?
        // break;
    }
}
```

By the way, if the question code is happening in `Update`, it might be best to call `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>` in `Start` (or, if the Rigidbody2D is ever removed and/or replaced, at those times as well) and cache the results, since it can be an expensive operation.

Comment: Thanks Ruzihm! I'll give this a shot and let you know, thanks for taking the time with this!

Answer (score 0):

Actually better than checking this manually would indeed be a `UI.Button` + additionally implementing a custom extension using the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) etc interfaces (note: the linked API is 2018, but this applies to 2020 as well, they just moved the API to a package and there it is not so well explained) like

```
public class HoldButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    // Called once when the button goes down (comparable to GetKeyDown)
    public UnityEvent OnButtonDown;
    // Called every frame while the button is pressed (comparable to GetKey)
    public UnityEvent WhilePressed;
    // Called once when the button goes up (comparable to GetKeyUp)
    public UnityEvent OnButtonUp;

    // Called if you hover with the mouse or drag an existing touch into the button
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Not sure if needed for OnPointerExit to work, doing nothing else
    }

    // Called when mouse or touch leaves the button
    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        OnButtonUp.Invoke();
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    // Called if you press the mouse or begin a touch over this button
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        OnButtonDown.Invoke();
        StartCoroutine (WhilePressedRoutine());
    }

    // Called if you release mouse or touch over this button
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        OnButtonUp.Invoke();
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressedRoutine()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            WhilePressed.Invoke();
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In these `UnityEvent`s you can reference your handler methods just like in the [`UI.Button.onClick`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) via the Inspector or on runtime via script.

So you can either attach this on a UI element (like a `Button`) and let the `EventSystem` of the scene call the pointer handlers.

Or you can even attach this to normal 3D objects! In such case this requires additionally

- A collider on your 3D object
- A `PhysicsRaycaster` component on your `Camera`

Or for a 2D object accordingly

- A Collider2D on your object
- A `Physics2DRaycaster` on your `Camera`

These interfaces work for both, mouse and touch input (except for the pointer enter probably because a touch can't just hover - at least not on all phones ;) )

Comment: In asker's code it seems like the button will activate even if the user presses outside the button then drags their finger into the button. If that's intentional, would you recommend just  adding `OnButtonDown.Invoke(); StartCoroutine (WhilePressedRoutine());` to `OnPointerEnter`? But if that's done, I'm not sure how you can read `PointerEventData` to skip that if the pointer is a hovered mouse pointer, but do you know a way?

Comment: @Ruzihm first part yes, UX wise it is a bit counter intuitive though and I would recommend to not do this ;) The second part is quite difficult indeed .. the EventSystem doesn't really differ anymore between pointers **but** yes you can use the [`PointerEventData.pointerId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.PointerEventData-pointerId.html) which is negative for mouse button input ;)